# compiler link independent static/dynamic library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, linkage

I would like to build my libtest.cpp source code as static/dynamic library (libtest.so) on Linux. I want to share this .so, and others can link to it with their compilers (different version). I would like to ask how to achieve it?

As I know, Intel MKL is a similar library, we download .h and .so, then link to it using our compiler.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

To create a static library with gcc(I'm assuming you're using gcc) use the following line:

```
g++ -c libtest.cpp -o libtest.o
ar  rcs libtest.a libtest.o
```

And for a shared library:

```
g++ -c -fPIC libtest.cpp -o libtest.o  
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.1 -o libtest.so.1.0.1  libtest.o
```

Comment: The lib built by this way depends on compiler and compiler version. When using other compiler to link (in other computer), there could have problems.

Comment: There is not any compiler & linker that can generate a global library file which then can be used by every pc on the earth. You may encounter problems from platform&architecture differences. But it has nothing to do with the compiler&linker since at the end, a compiler generates an object code according to specified standard. In my answer, I assumed that "others" have modern compilers and have the same platform & architecture since you didn't specify otherwise